# Adding a Category Attribute in Magento 1.8.1

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I am currently trying to add a new category attribute to the category admin screen in Magento 1.8.1, I am having issues with getting anything to show though.

The only code examples I can find include mysql4, however I thought this had been retired? Please can anyone point us in the right direction here.

I can see my extension under Config > Advanced and in the core_resources table. But not in the front end of the site.

Comment: Can you share the file names and the code from install script?

Comment: using mysql4-install-0.0.1.php and config.xml

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We've tried this recently with 1.8.2.0. You don't really need to create a module just to add a category attribute, *once*. It seems such a waste to go through so much file *cruft* to get something installed just once.

Category attributes tend to stay permanently once installed so what worked better for us is to just use a one-off script. Save this one right at magento root.

```
    <?php

    require_once "app/Mage.php";

    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));


    $installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup;

    // change details below:
    $attribute  = array(
        'type' => 'int',
        'label'=> 'Your attribute label',
        'input' => 'text',
        'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'visible' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'default' => "",
        'group' => "General Information"
    );

    $installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'your_attribute_code', $attribute);

    $installer->endSetup();
```

Save it as `add_category_attribute.php` or something else memorable for you.

You can either use the browser to get to this file, or use `php-cli` to run this:

```
php -f add_category_attribute.php
```

Good luck.

Comment: Please Note: if you are interested in having this new category attribute accept text and not just integers be sure to change 'type' ==> 'int' to 'text'; if you need a text area, change 'input'==>'text' to 'textarea'; please consider this beforehand, otherwise you will end up with a number of mistaken category fields cluttering your category section

Comment: That works... quick question... hot to get the value in the front ? Thanks

Comment: Great, Its working fine. But is this standard way to add attributes in category?

Comment: As i mentioned at the start of my answer, usually this is done with a module with a migration file in it. But usually that's way harder, so if you can't bother -- use a one-off script such as the above. @dineshkashera

Answer (score 3):

Change the file name from `mysql4-install-0.0.1.php` to `install-0.0.1.php`

Answer (score 2):

@h3nr1ke You can get attribute with:

```
$category = Mage::registry('current_category');
if ($category){
   $value = $category->getData('YOUR_CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTE_CODE');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this script in your magento root folder to create Attribute

```
<?php  

require_once('app/Mage.php');
 Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));

$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();   
$entityTypeId = $installer->getEntityTypeId('catalog_category');
$attributeSetId = $installer->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);

if (!$installer->getAttributeId($entityTypeId, 'shipping_content')) {
    $installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'shipping_content', array(
         'type'              => 'text',
'backend'           => '',
'frontend'          => '',
'label'             => 'Short description',
'input'             => 'textarea',
'class'             => '',
'source'            => '',
'global'            => '0',
'visible'           => true,
'required'          => false,
'user_defined'      => true,
'default'           => '',
'searchable'        => false,
'filterable'        => false,
'comparable'        => false,
'visible_on_front'  => true,
'used_in_product_listing' => false,
'unique'            => false,
'wysiwyg_enabled'   => true,
'apply_to'          => '',
'is_configurable'   => true
    ));


    $installer->updateAttribute($entityTypeId, 'shipping_content', 'is_wysiwyg_enabled', 1);
    $installer->updateAttribute($entityTypeId, 'shipping_content', 'is_html_allowed_on_front', 1);


}


$installer->endSetup();

?>
```

For Remove Category Attribute

```
<?php  

require_once('app/Mage.php');
 Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));

 $installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup;
 $installer->startSetup();
 $installer->removeAttribute('catalog_category', 'shipping_content');
 $installer->endSetup();

?>
```